# QGIS: layer scale visibility

Tags: qgis, symbology, scale

I need to display a line-type layer differently according to scale. Do I necessarily have to use a rule-based representation and make several different rules (one per scale interval) or is it possible to achieve that within a single symbol representation? I guess the answer is the first one, but just in case it could be done easier...

Comment: I think you are right in that you would need to use rule-based rendering. Don't see this option for single symbols.